# Change datatype of column in a Dataframe in Julia

Tags: julia, julia-dataframe

I have a dataframe `df = DataFrame(CSV.File("file.csv", delim=";;"))`.
The dataframe has three columns (column1 = Date, column2 = String31, column3 = String15).

```
column1    |  column2   |  column3
 date      |  String31  |  String15
2022-06-29 |    Test    |   100.00
```

Only column1 has the right datatype. I would like to change both column2 (to just String) and column3 (to Real or Float64). I managed to change column two, but when I tried to change column3 I got that I can't change string to real.

How would I go about to change these two columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On `column2` I would recommend leaving it as `String31` unless you run into an issue with that (and if you do maybe raise an issue with the [`InlineStrings.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaStrings/InlineStrings.jl) package). `String31` is a datatype mainly aimed at data analysis workflows where large number of strings are created in memory (such as in a long DataFrame column), which puts a lot of pressure on Julia's garbage collector. Working with InlineStrings like `String31` is therefore likely to speed up the analysis in many cases (this won't matter if your data set is small).

For `column3`, if you want to get a number from a string you need to `parse` it:

```
julia> parse(Float64, "100.0")
100.0
```

You can apply this to the whole column by broadcasting:

```
df.column2 = parse.(Float64, df.column2)
```

That said, this operation is likely to fail, because if it would work CSV.jl would have parsed the column as numeric already. The fact that the column is `String` tells you that there's likely something in there which can't be parsed as a number - one popular example is a thousands separator (e.g. in files that came from Excel).

`parse` will however tell you where it failed:

```
julia> parse.(Float64, ["100.0", "1,000.0"])
ERROR: ArgumentError: cannot parse "1,000.0" as Float64
```

In this case you would to `parse.(Float64, replace.(df.column2, "," => ""))` to remove thousands separators.

[If `parse` just works without any changes you might have discovered a bug in `CSV.jl`s type detection algorithm which might be worth filing an issue for.]